# Polar symmetry of $r = \cos(2\theta)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, curves, polar-coordinates

For the polar curve

$$r = \cos(2\theta)$$

I have run through the tests for polar symmetry about the $y$-axis, the $x$-axis and about the origin. According to the replacements for $(r,\theta)$, this function appears to only have symmetry about the $x$-axis since replacing $(r,\theta)$ with $(-r,-\theta)$ and $(-r, \theta)$ yield the equation

$$
r = -\cos(2\theta)
,$$

which is a different equation from the original.  However, a quick visual verification on Desmos indicates that this graph appears to have symmetry with regards to the $x,y$-axes and also the origin.

Since the resulting equation is not the same as $r = \cos(2\theta)$, for the y-axis and origin symmetry tests, would we still say that the polar function has symmetry about the $y$-axis and origin due to its graph?

Comment: The symmetry tests say that if the test holds, then the graph will exhibit the type of symmetry in question.  However, the symmetry tests are not if and only if statements.  Therefore, if the symmetry test does not hold, you will have to draw the graph to test for symmetry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A polar graph is symmetric with respect to $r=\frac{\pi}{2}$ [the $y$-axis] if replacing $(r,\theta)$ with either $(r,\pi-\theta)$ or $(-r,-\theta)$ gives an equivalent equation.

$r=\cos(2(\pi-\theta))=\cos(2\theta)$ so the polar graph is symmetric with respect to the $y$-axis.

A polar graph is symmetric with respect the pole [the origin] if replacing $(r,\theta)$ with either $(r,\pi+\theta)$ or $(-r,\theta)$ gives an equivalent equation.

$r=\cos(2(\pi+\theta))=\cos(2\theta)$ so the graph is symmetric with respect to the origin.